# Array of records to read using functions

Tags: arrays, function, program-entry-point, record, pascal

I am having problems in reading the array of records using my ReadAllCars function. How do I get to read all 3 inputs of the Car records into the Cars array?:

```
type 
    Car = record
        id: String;
        manufacturer: String;
        model: String;
        reg: String;
    end;

var
Cars: array[0..2] of Car;

function ReadString(prompt: String): String; 
begin
    Write(prompt);
    ReadLn(result);
end;

function ReadCar(prompt: String): Car)
begin
    WriteLn(prompt);
    result.id := ReadString('Please enter the car id: ');
    result.manufacturer := ReadString('Please enter the manufacturer: ');
    result.model := ReadString('Please enter the car model: ');
    result.reg := ReadString('Please enter the car registration: ');
end;


function ReadAllCars(count: Integer): Cars;
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to count-1 do
    begin
        ReadCar('Please enter the car details');
    end;
end;

procedure Main();

var
    Cars: array[0..2] of Car;
begin
    Cars := ReadAllCars(3);

end;
```

I am getting an error of Type identifier expected

Comment: The error message indicate on which row and which character the error was detected, no? You have an erroneous character in a function header. You have declared an `array of car` twice. When you read al cars you don't do anything with the result of `ReadCar()`.

Comment: Ok. I have changed my ReadAllCars to be 


    function ReadAllCars(count: Integer): Cars;
    var
     i: Integer;
    begin
     for i := 0 to count-1 do
     begin
      Cars[i] := ReadCar('Enter car details');
     end;
    end;

Answer (score 0):

May I first suggest that you start using a common practice of naming type declarations as T+name. F.ex. a type declaring a car is named `TCar`. Then, an instance of a `TCar` could be called, well, `Car`. Now you would immediately see that one is a type and the other is an instance.

The actual problem for which you got the error message "Type identifier expected" is that you are using a variable declaration as if it were a type, namely

```
var
  Cars: array[0..2] of Car;
```

You are using this as a result **type** for the `ReadAllCars()` and that is the error. Instead you need to declare a type `TCars`

```
type
  TCars: array[0..2] of TCar;
```

Put this type declaration immediately after the existing type declaration for `Car`, which I hope you will rename to `TCar`.

Thus, `TCars` would be the result type of the function `ReadAllCars()`

Finally, to change the variable that holds all the cars, you would write

```
var
  Cars: TCars;
```